# Change queryset of ModelChoiceField in __init__ of forms.Form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am currently having issue to override `__init__()` for `forms.Form`.

### Base Form

```
class ReportsMainForm(forms.Form):
 ---- #Some fields
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReportsMainForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Child Form

```
class Child(ReportsMainForm):
    customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Customer.objects.none(), label="Customer", empty_label=None, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

### Problem

The problem here is, my `queryset` has not been updated. What am i missing?

Comment: the `__init__` belong which class ? why it call super with `ProjectsBySalesman` ?

Comment: You've split up the init method from the rest of the class in separate snippets, which makes it very hard to see what's going on. Please edit your question, showing the code *exactly* as it appears in your project, paying particular attention to indentation.

Comment: @sax Both classess have their own __init__()

Comment: You should change also widget's allowed choices

Comment: Hmm, this should work exactly as it is: I've used identical code many times in the past.

Comment: Exactly, that what making me wonder why i need to update the widget attrib

Answer (score 3):

Try to change also widget's queryset (ehm... choices):

```
self.fields['customer'].queryset = ...
self.fields['customer'].widget.choices = self.fields['customer'].choices
```

**WHY?**

Inspecting the code (see django.forms.model.ModelChoiceField), when a queryset is set on the field widget's choice are also updated (and that is good):

But choices are cached on the field and so they are always the same...

I think this is a bug, since there is the explicit option "cache_choices" on field init, which is defaulted to False.

Comment: Can you please explain this behavior? this seems wierd. Why we need to change the widget? The code works though

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong

```
super(ProjectsBySalesman, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

should be

```
super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to change the name to child. i have updated the question.